# Java - Collection

Tags: java, collections

I'm working on my first java project and I have a question. The question should be quiet simple (though the the code is not that short, but there's no reason to be intimidated :) ). I create a basic roleplaying-game and I have an abstract class "Character" that defines each character. Among its subclasses you can find Mage, who has a Spellbook (Map). Spellbook class offers methods like addToSpellbook, that works fine. In addition I have an Inventory class that has addToInventory method, which is quit identical to addToSpellbook.

My question is as follows - why can I use In the main method addToSpellbook and can't use AddToInventory?

I guess the reason is that Map doesn't have AddToInventory, so I should override put, but still, how can I use addToSpellbook ?

```
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    CharacterCreator heroCreator = new CharacterCreator();
    CharacterCreator.showAllClasses();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int scan = sc.nextInt();
    String chosenClass = CharacterCreator.getCharacterClass(scan);
    Character hero = CharacterCreator.createCharacter(chosenClass);
    try {
        hero.displayCharacter();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problem displaying character data");
    }

    hero.getInventory().addToInventory("Long sword");


    CharacterCreator heroCreator2 = new CharacterCreator();
    CharacterCreator.showAllClasses();

    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int scan2 = sc.nextInt();
    String chosenClass2 = CharacterCreator.getCharacterClass(scan2);
    Character hero2 = CharacterCreator.createCharacter(chosenClass2);
    try {
        hero2.displayCharacter();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }

    if(hero instanceof Mage) {
        ((Mage)hero).getSpellBook().addToSpellBook("Magic Missiles");
        ((Mage)hero).getSpellBook().addToSpellBook("Fireball");
        ((Mage)hero).getSpellBook().addToSpellBook("Mage Armor");

        ((Mage)hero).getSpellBook().showSpellBook();
        ((Mage)hero).getSpellBook().getSpellFromSpellbook("Fireball").castSpell(hero, hero2);
        ((Mage)hero).getSpellBook().getSpellFromSpellbook("Magic Missiles").castSpell(hero, hero2);
        ((Mage)hero).getSpellBook().getSpellFromSpellbook("Mage Armor").castSpell(hero, hero);

    }


}

}


abstract public class Character {



private Equipment equipment;

private Map<String, Integer> inventory;



protected Character(String name){

    equipment = new Equipment();

    inventory = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

}

protected Character(String name, int lvl){


    equipment = new Equipment();

    inventory = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

}


}






public Equipment getEquipment() { return equipment; }
public Map getInventory() { return inventory; }


}

public class Inventory {

private Map<String,Integer> inventory;

Inventory() {

    inventory = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

public void addToInventory(String item) {

    boolean found = false;

    try {
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iter = inventory.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> newItem = iter.next();
            if (newItem.getKey() == item) {
                inventory.put(item, inventory.get(newItem) + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(item + " : adding failed");
    }

    if (!found) {
        inventory.put(item,1);
    }

}


public void showInventory() {

    System.out.println("Show Inventory: ");

    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry: inventory.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println( entry.getKey()  + ", quantity: " + entry.getValue() );
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

}


public class Mage extends Character {


private SpellBook spellBook;


public Mage(String name) {

    super(name);

    SpellBook spellbook = new SpellBook();

}

protected Mage(String name, int lvl){

    super(name, lvl);


    spellBook = new SpellBook();


}


public SpellBook getSpellBook() { return spellBook; }


}



}


public class SpellBook {

private Map<String, Spell> spellBook;

SpellBook() {

    spellBook = new HashMap<String, Spell>();
}

public Map getSpellBook() { return spellBook; }


public void addToSpellBook(String spellName) {

    Spell newSpell = null;

    try {

        if (DamageSpell.getSpell(spellName) != null) {
            newSpell = DamageSpell.getSpell(spellName);
        } else if (ChangeStatSpell.getSpell(spellName) != null) {
            newSpell = ChangeStatSpell.getSpell(spellName);
        }

        System.out.println(newSpell.getSpellName() + " has been added to the spellbook");
        spellBook.put(newSpell.getSpellName(), newSpell);

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Adding " + spellName +"to spellbook has failed");
    }

}


public void showSpellBook() {

    System.out.println("Show spellbook: ");

    for (Iterator<String> iter = spellBook.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        String spell = iter.next();
        System.out.println(spell);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public Spell getSpellFromSpellbook(String spellName) {

    Spell spl = null;

    //Spell splGet = spellBook.get(spellName); /* straight forward   implementation*/
   // System.out.println("The spell " + splGet.getSpellName() + " has been retrived from the spellbook by using get method");

    try {
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Spell>> iter = spellBook.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, Spell> spell = iter.next();
            if (spell.getKey() == spellName) {
                spl =  spell.getValue();
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(spellName + " : no such spell in spellbook");
    }
   return spl;

}

}
```

Comment: Please shrink your code to the relevant parts. Thanks.

Comment: I'm working on it, in a minute

Comment: It's much shorter now :)

Comment: Thanks :). But I think @Eran has solved the problem, right? :)

Comment: You should change the class name Character, if possible, because there is a java.lang.Character and this can cause a bit of confusion when other people read your code.

Comment: Your addToInventory method is not using HashMap properly. Study HashMap (and Map) in detail in the API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getInventory()` returns a `Map` and `Map` doesn't have the `addToInventory()` method.
`getInventory()` should add an `Inventory` instance.

Comment: I know, that's exactly what I mentioned.

Comment: But why addToSpellbook works ? both methods are almost identical, so as the implementation for spellbook and inventory

Comment: @Niminim `getSpellBook()` (in the `Mage` class) returns a `SpellBook` which has an `addToSpellbook ` method.

Comment: Now getInventory return Inventory  - public Inventory getInventory() { return inventory; } , but I get a compilation error:

Comment: incompatible types java.util.map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer> can't be converted to Game.Inventory

Comment: @Niminim The `inventory` variable contains a `Map`, so changing the return type of the method makes no difference. You have to change the type of `inventory` too.

Comment: I mixed things up while writing Inventory, thanks :)